Why is atlas search not processing numbers?
I want to use MongoDB Atlas search to search in my app. I have an index called vehicle. It is not processing any number. I don't know why. I have looked through a few of the questions here but I didn't find the answer I need.
I have tried replacing year and registration id with string type but it still didn't give me any results. I have also tried making the dynamic mapping both true and false.
I also want to add this search to my react app. Is it possible and what do I use? How do I connect the search function to my app. I am already using my collections in my app to display data.
Please be patient with me as I am new.
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "Color": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "License Plate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Make": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Model": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Owner": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Registration ID": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "Year": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  }
}

This is an example of what I have in my collection:
"Registration ID": 1234567,
"License Plate": "ABC123",
"Make": "Toyota",
"Model": "Corolla",
"Year": 2015,
"Color": "Blue",
"Owner": "John Smith"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
